# Meaning of COPY Command Used by Visual Studio Build?

Tags: visual-studio, build

I don't quite understand the \ and \.. syntax in the compile error I'm getting

> Error 6 The command " copy
>   c:\project\new\..
>   \new\bin\x64\debug\garmin.dll
>   c:\project\new\bin\x64\Debug\ "
>   exited with a code 1.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: And the reason why it is printed that way is because the path is a combination of two or more (relative) paths stored in two locations in the project config. VS just appends them and passes them to the OS to figure out where the file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\..\`  simply means "the parent directory". So in this case, `\new\..\new\` contains redundancy, and simply means `\new\`. You are trying to copy a file to the directory it is already in, but it won't happen because the file already exists (and perhaps is in use?)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as from the command line.  `..` is on directory "up".